# Система модулей и плагинов ASP.NET MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, плагин, asp.net-core, addons

Мы делаем CMS, и хотим сделать возможность плагинов для неё.
Например: есть статья, и плагин с помощью которого к статье можно ставить лайки.
Так вот, как организовать плагинность проекта.

Я понимаю как я могу делать встраивание плагина в действие+вьюшку. Можно сделать так:
У плагина есть функция, например `AddLikestToArticle`
У неё аттрибут `[PluginModule(ToAction: "ActionName", ToController: "ControllerName")]`
Далее при подключении плагина, все функции с данным атрибутом регистрируются в системе.
В момент вызова дейтсивя `ActionName` после того как оно уже веруно HTML результатя парсю в HTML DOM этот результат и вызываю `AddLikestToArticle` применяю его к полученному результату.

Но как сделать плагин к классам, и в особенности к классам которые хранятся в базе данных черезе `EF`. Плагин может расширять классы (добавлять столбы в таблицы), или даже добавлять новые классы. Как быть с `DbContext`, как его расширять плагином?

Меня интересуют все подходы которые могут быть. Есть ли какие-то готовые системы для плагинности/модульности?

Как пока я думаю это можно сделать.
Расширять классы через наследование. При этом у каждого модуля может быть свой класс наследник. Остаётся вопрос как теперь собрать (максимально широкий) DbContext. Я думаю можно собрать этот файл через код, то есть собрать его код автоматически и потом на-лету скомпилировать, и через IoC использовать именно его.

Comment: Какой нибудь интерфейс IExtesntions { object getExtenstions(); } и через DI разбирать где нужно. Хотя костыльное решение.

Comment: @QuaternioNoir а что такое Dl?

Comment: Depency Injection, например какой нибудь autofac.

Comment: @QuaternioNoir что-то не могу найти никакой документации по IExtensions

Comment: Ох, простите) Я имел ввиду написать собственный интерфейс для описания плагинов.

Comment: Не хотел вас запутать)

Comment: @QuaternioNoir нашёл пока искал IExtension компонент MEF, как раз на эту тему - https://habrahabr.ru/post/95809/ , так что спасибо, ешё не полностью уверен что подойдёт, буду читать